# How do we use %sysfunc to calculate mean of numeric variable?

Tags: macros, sas

I m trying to calculate average of a numeric variable in title of macro. The code looks like this:

```
title "Using sysfunc to evaluate mean %sysfunc((mean(Total_retail_price)) )"
```

Its giving an error which says :

> ERROR: Function name missing in %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function reference.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

```
%macro type(year=,type=);

proc print data=salesxls ;

title " using sysfunc to evaluate  mean %sysfunc((mean(Total_retail_price)) )";

where year(order_date)=&year. and Order_type=&type;

format order_date year4.;

run;
%mend type;
```

p.s newbie here

Comment: what is that you have and what should output be

Comment: Just trying to output  average of a numeric variable in title,

Comment: @Kiran please see edit, Thanks

Comment: trying to help, so that someone understands. what is Total_retail_price

Comment: It is a Numeric variable in the Data that is been used

Comment: data values you cannot use in %sysfunc,

Answer (score 3):

SAS doesn't recognize the variable `Total_Retail_Price` in that context and most statistical functions can't be called in that manner.

You would need to assign the mean value to a macro variable. Here is one example.

```
proc sql noprint;
select mean(Total_Retail_Price) into: mean_value
from salesxls
where year(order_date)=&year. and Order_type=&type;
quit;
```

Now you can add the new macro variable, `mean_value` into your title.

```
title "The mean of Total Retail Price is: &mean_value.";
```

Now the complete macro would look like this:

```
%macro type(year=,type=);
proc sql noprint;
select mean(Total_Retail_Price) into: mean_value
from salesxls
where year(order_date)=&year. and Order_type=&type;
quit;

proc print data=salesxls ;    
title "The mean of Total Retail Price is: &mean_value."; 
where year(order_date)=&year. and Order_type=&type;    
format order_date year4.;
run;
%mend type;
```

Answer (score 1):

For the case of multiple groups a single macro variable will not be useful.

A `BY` variable name or value can be displayed in a `TITLE` statement using special tokens --  `#BYVAL<n>`, `#BYVAR<n>`, `#BYVAL(<var>)` and `#BYVAR(<var>)`.

Create a `view` with a column for the price mean, such that it will be a by variable.  Use that column in the `by` statement and a special token in the `title`.

```
proc sql;
  create view work.cars_v as select 
  cars.*
  , mean(msrp) as mean_price format=dollar7. /* automatic remerge */
  from sashelp.cars
  group by Make,Type
  ;

options nocenter nobyline;

proc print data=work.cars_v;
  title "#byval(make) #byval(Type), Average MSRP:#byval(mean_price)";
  by Make Type mean_price;
  var Model Origin DriveTrain EngineSize Cylinders MSRP;
run;
```

Listing

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Acura SUV, Average MSRP:$36,945

                               Drive    Engine
     Obs    Model    Origin    Train     Size     Cylinders        MSRP

       1     MDX      Asia      All       3.5         6         $36,945

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Acura Sedan, Average MSRP:$34,772

                                                 Drive    Engine
     Obs    Model                      Origin    Train     Size     Cylinders        MSRP

       2    RSX Type S 2dr              Asia     Front      2.0         4         $23,820
       3    TSX 4dr                     Asia     Front      2.4         4         $26,990
       4    TL 4dr                      Asia     Front      3.2         6         $33,195
       5    3.5 RL 4dr                  Asia     Front      3.5         6         $43,755
       6    3.5 RL w/Navigation 4dr     Asia     Front      3.5         6         $46,100

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Acura Sports, Average MSRP:$89,765

                                                Drive    Engine
     Obs            Model             Origin    Train     Size     Cylinders        MSRP

       7    NSX coupe 2dr manual S     Asia     Rear       3.2         6         $89,765

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

etc …
```